# Android - Want to create a form like create my profile view in the contact application?

Tags: android

I want to learn how to create a form same as one that is given in the contact application of android. You can see that form when you open your contact application and click on create my profile image in the option menu.

If you know any tutorial that have sample code to create such form , plz give me those links. I am also searching for such tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android :
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html

Other:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-forms/

http://vimaltuts.com/android/finalize-your-login-form-part-3

There are many more out there. But I would suggest, you start from the one on the Android documentation site - [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html).

Comment: I have already created these types of form. Now i want to create forms like create my profile form like contact application create profile form. With some advance feature like select user image from existing gallery images or click user image from camera.

Comment: Then you need try on your own. These resources are more than sufficient to get you started. If you want spoon feeding then that's a different case.